# get the state of a function component for my url in getStaticProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

i want to fetch data from an input so i create a controlled component like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'


type Props = {data:any};


function Locality({data}: Props) {

const [city, setCity] = useState("13000");

return(

 <input
  list="city"
  type="text"
  placeholder={`Code postale, France`}
  onChange={(e) => {
   setCity(e.target.value) ;
   }}
  />
 )
}
```

i want to fetch an url according to the city set in the state but i don't know how to give this state to my fetch below:

```
export async function getStaticProps(){
const getDataUrl:string = `https://geo.api.gouv.fr/communes?codePostal=${city}&format=geojson`

const result = await axios.get(getDataUrl)
const data = result.data

  return {
    props:{
      data : data.data[0].attributes
    }
  }
}
```

any idea ?

Comment: `getStaticProps` is for getting build-time data on the server. `React.useState` is for managing run-time state, on the client

Comment: oh yes ok i see now just with a useEffect it works ^^ sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @ksav, you would need to use some local state, but also, an effect to fetch the data.

Here is an example how to do that: (untested, for the idea)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'


type Props = {data:any};


function Locality({data}: Props) {

const [city, setCity] = useState("13000");
// That will contain the result of the fetch
const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false)
const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

useEffect(function fetchResults() {

      const getDataUrl:string = `https://geo.api.gouv.fr/communes?codePostal=${city}&format=geojson`
      setIsFetching(true)
      const result = axios.get(getDataUrl).then(res => {
        const data = result.data

        setResult(data.data[0].attributes)
      }).catch(setError).finally(() => {
        setIsFetching(false)
      })
}

return(

 <input
  list="city"
  type="text"
  placeholder={`Code postale, France`}
  onChange={(e) => {
   setCity(e.target.value) ;
   }}
  />{isFetching && 'Loading...'}
{!error && !isFetching && 
<div>Result for {city}: {result}</div>}
 )
}
```

If you use the above effect that I or @ksav suggested, I suggest you look for XHR cancelation and effect debouncing, to avoid bugs that *will* occur as the user types in the box and many requests are sent at the same time. For example if I type '75000', it will send 5 requests, and if the 3rd request is the slowest, result can finally contain the result for `750`, not `75000`.

Answer (score 2):

nextjs [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) is for getting build-time data on the server. `React.useState` is for managing run-time state, on the client

If fetching your data relies on some user interaction, try doing this on the client with `useEffect` and `useState`

```
function Locality({ data }) {
  const [city, setCity] = useState("13007");
  const [features, setFeatures] = useState({});

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const url = `https://geo.api.gouv.fr/communes?codePostal=${city}&format=geojson`;

    const result = await axios.get(url);
    const data = result.data.features;

    setFeatures(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [city]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={city}
        type="text"
        placeholder={`Code postale, France`}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCity(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(features, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit thirsty-joana-7pgrym]

You might also want to investigate nextjs [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)